# Singular integrals on compact manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, differential-operators

I've been trying to find a reference for a certain thing for a while now, without success. My setting is the following.

I've a compact smooth Riemannian manifold $M$. For $r>0$ (which is supposed to be small) denote $$k_r(t)=\frac{\varphi(t/r)}{t^{n-1}}$$ where  $\varphi:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, $spt(\varphi)\subset (0,1)$ and $\varphi\equiv 1$ on $(0,1/2)$, and define the "convolution" $$k_r\ast g (x)=\int_Mk_r(d(x,z))g(z)d z, \ g\in L^p(M).$$

The operator defined by this is bounded $L^p\to L^p$ (and in fact $\|k_r\ast g\|_p\to 0$ as $r\to 0$). However it should also map $L^p$ to $W^{1,p}$ boundedly, with a bound on the norm *independent of $r$*. (The kernel is a smooth cutoff-version of the Riesz potential so in $\mathbb{R}^n$ this is true.) The first problem I face is showing that the distributional gradient of $k_r\ast g$ is given by $$\nabla_x(k_r\ast g)\xi= PV \int_Mk_r'(d(x,z))\langle \nabla_xd_z,\xi\rangle g(z)dz,\ \xi\in T_xM$$ for a.e. $x\in M$ (this is the analogue of the normal procedure for the Euclidean case) and the second to show that this produces a bounded operator $L^p\to L^p$. (Since $k_r'(t)=\frac{\varphi'(t/r)}{rt^{n-1}}-(n-1)\frac{\varphi(t/r)}{t^n}$ the latter integral involves a subcritical kernel and a Riesz kernel -type term).

On an intuitive level, given that we take $r>0$ small, everything should work, and I would like to just state these as facts and give a reference. However I haven't been able to *find* a (readable to a nonspecialist) reference for the basic facts of singular integrals on (compact) manifolds, and I certainly do not want to rewrite classical proofs in this setting. Therefore a reference, or any help, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that you probably only want to consider $r>0$ very small. If $r$ is smaller than the injectivity radius of $M$ (which is positive by compactness), every metric ball is diffeomorphic to a Euclidean ball under the exponential map. If $r$ continues to shrink, then the pullbacks of the suitably rescaled Riemannian metrics on a fixed ball in a tangent space converge uniformly to a Euclidean metric. This way, you can control what happens for very small $r$. Would that already help?

Comment: @ Sebastian Goette Indeed, that is the idea. I'm basically looking for a reference for the fact that for $r$ smaller than the injectivity radius, the PV exists and defines a bounded operator. I've seen singular integrals treated only in $R^n$ and I don't want to repeat the same arguments  to obtain the manifold version of these facts.